# Storing a Range in a model: 2x integer fields or new table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm newish to Rails and I'm trying to build an app for fun. One of the projects I've started working on is similar to a directory where I aggregate information for ease of access.

One of the fields in my model is a range. For example, min-size = 5, max-size = 10. This just represents that an entry can have a value within that range.

I'd like to be able to search the database using the range as the criteria. So for example, find all entries whose range falls within min-size = 4, max-size = 11.

I've currently implemented this as two integer columns in the database, but some resources here on StackOverflow are making me think that I should store this as a separate table. How should I do this?

Comment: The way you're doing it is correct -- no need to store that data in a separate table.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't want to end up causing myself more work so I thought I would ask.

Comment: Postgres has a native range type. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html